# html/js inline editor behaviour

Tags: support, editor

I don't understand the behaviour of the inline editor for html/js snippets; why is it showing `<pre>some uuid</pre>` in the preview while editing, when

```
<!-- begin snippet: html hide: false--><!-- language: lang-html -->
<!-- end snippet -->
```

is indented? (there is no whitespace between `false` and `-->` just to let the snippet above to render)

```
    <table border="1">
    <tr>
    <td>day</td>
    <td>price</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>1,194</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>796</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>995</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>995</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>995</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Taken from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33878911/how-to-create-daily-report-from-mysql (have a look at the edit history there)

Comment: You're taking your snippet and indenting it 4 spaces, which confuses the parser. When I edit your question and remove the 4 spaces in front of each line, it looks normal...

Comment: yep that's what happens; I don't understand the behavior, is that a bug, a partially implemented feature, or what?

Comment: The snippet editor will not add those extra 4 spaces around the HTML comments, so it's not a bug. Are you highlighting the code and clicking the `{ }` button? I could see that causing the problem...